# logrotate problem with rotating unusuall logs

Tags: centos, logrotate

I have a problem with logrotate. The application itself produces following logs:
xxx.log
and at 23:59 the application changes the log to:
xxx.log.2019-01-05
and so on. Right now I am getting following in the log directory:

```
xxx.log
xxx.log.2019-01-01
xxx.log.2019-01-02
```

etc.

What I need to to is want to rotate the logs that get created on 23:59 and not to touch the `xxx.log` file itself.

I have tried with following logrotate rule:

```
/var/log/xxx/xxx/xxx.log.* {
        daily
        missingok
        rotate 30
        compress
        notifempty
         copytruncate
        nosharedscripts
        prerotate
                bash -c "[[ ! $1 =~ *.gz ]]"
        endscript
}
```

But first of all logrotate does not compress the log that was created last and it also adds .1.gz extension to previously compressed files.

Answer (score 0):

> logrotate does not compress the log that was created last

Do you have "delaycompress" defined in /etc/logrotate.conf? Per [logrotate man](https://manpages.debian.org/jessie/logrotate/logrotate.8.en.html):

> **delaycompress**
>
> Postpone compression of the previous log file to the next rotation cycle.

---

> it also adds .1.gz extension

While you're at the aforementioned man page, you should check out what the "extension" option does:

> **extension *ext***
>
> Log files with *ext* extension can keep it after the rotation.